# Why does $(^n a)$ eventually become constant modulo $\phi (n)$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

*Sorry, I changed this question from another one I delete a few minutes ago, but I'm slightly confused on this question."*

In the [following link](https://sites.math.northwestern.edu/%7Emlerma/problem_solving/solutions/event_const.pdf), the statement in Case $1$, "since $\phi(m) < m$, by induction hypothesis, $(^n a) \text{ mod } \phi(m)$ is eventually constant" doesn't make a lot of sense to me can someone elaborate on that?

To elaborate, the base question is that
$$1,a,a^a,...$$
eventually becomes constant modulo $n.$

Comment: What doesn't make sense about it? It's just the induction hypothesis, you assume that ${}^na \pmod k$ is eventually constant for all $k \leq m - 1$, and use that to show that it holds for $k = m$.

Comment: Because $\phi(n)<n$  so the value eventually reaches $1$ on iteration.

Comment: There's no need to iterate here since they use strong induction.

Comment: @Rushy Do you mean to say it's just a hypothesis?

Comment: Yes, in the base case you show that it holds for all $n > 0$ and $m = 2$, then you assume that it holds for all modulo up to $m - 1$, and use that to show it holds for $m$.

Comment: @Rushy I am confused why $ \phi(m) < m$ is mentioned then.

Comment: The idea is by Euler's theorem, ${}^{(n + 1)}a \equiv a^{{}^na \bmod \phi(m)} \pmod m$. Now, $\phi(m) < m$, so you can apply the induction hypothesis to ${}^na \bmod \phi(m)$ and conclude that it is eventually constant. Hence $a^{{}^na \bmod \phi(m)}$ is eventually constant. Thus ${}^{(n + 1)}a \bmod m$ is eventually constant, since this is equivalent to $a^{{}^na \bmod \phi(m)}$.

Comment: @Rushy Oh wait, I see, it was simple as that. $\phi(m) < m$ was only referring to induction. Jeez man, I am the stupid I've ever been at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural numbers are a well order ( meaning there's a least element). This means $\phi(n)<n$ which implies $\phi(\phi(n))<\phi(n)$ etc. Will eventually hit the lowest element. Since modulo $1$ always returns $0$ we get everything at or above that level doesn't affect the outcome.

Comment: More or less helped me out, thanks, I will still accept as an answer.